# Should check every numeral of number and got bad output

Tags: python, loops, math, output

i have a task:
got a range on input
[x;y]
then i should check every number from that range and check every numeral in number. if its odd, i should print it
for example: 3, 20
i should print 4,6,8,20

```
def check(num):
if int(num) % 2 == 0:
    return True


x, y = int(input()), int(input())

numbers = []
if x <= y:
while x != y:
    for i in str(x):
        if check(i):
            numbers.append(x)
    x += 1

else:
while y != x:
    for i in str(y):
        i = int(i)
        if check(i):
            numbers.append(y)
    y += 1
if y == x:
    for i in str(x):
        if check(i):
            numbers.append(x)
print(numbers)
```

it prints
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24, 24, 25, 26, 26, 27, 28, 28, 29]
instead of 2,4,6,8,20,22,24,26,28

Comment: The problem is a bit unclear. Do you mean to print all numbers in the range where all digits in the number are even? Your post says "odd".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking and approving based on a single digit for each number. You should check all of them before appending the entire number. That's why you get `22` twice: once for the first `2` and once for the second. You get `10`, because even though `1` is odd, `0` is even and so you append it to your list.

Move the check for the entire number into the function `check` and have it return `True` *only* if all digits are even. This shortens your code. Also note that you can trivially swap `x` and `y` if the user entered them in the wrong order.

The function `check` immediately returns `False` as soon as it finds a digit `i` is odd, and you can see it can only return `True` if the loop ended and all digits were even.

```py
    def check(num):
        for i in str(num):
            if int(i) % 2 != 0:
                return False
        return True


    x, y = int(input()), int(input())
    if x > y:
        x,y = y,x

    numbers = []

    while x <= y:
        if check(x):
            numbers.append(x)
        x += 1
    print (numbers)
```

Result, with `3` and `20` entered (but `20` and `3` would also work):

```
[4, 6, 8, 20]
```